# How do I calculation to see if Thyristor complies with DO-160G indirect lightning protection

Tags: ethernet, amperage, surge-protection, thyristor, lightning

I have been working with TVS diode and found that the capacitance of tvs diode is large; therefore, I will not be able to use tvs diode.

Thyristor, on the other hand, has low capacitance for high speed ethernet data. Unlike tvs diode which displays Power peak vs time chart (I could calculate using the chart), how do I calculate  for thyristor amperage at different waveform?

Comment: Why not use shielded ethernet cable then you can apply surge protection to the shield and massively reduce the protection problem on the actual data lines.

Comment: The ethernet that I am using has a shield on it. I will be connecting the shield ethernet to ground.

Comment: Surges will be applied to the shield and your TVS requirements will be very much reduced.